# Strategy Pattern and Dependency Injection in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have an *Strategy* interface, that is implemented by *StrategyA* and *StrategyB*, both of them are defined as **@Component**'s and they have an **@Autowired** attribute as well, how can I do to obtain an instance of one of them based on an String value?

This is my Controller's action, that should perform the strategy:

```
@RequestMapping("/blabla")
public void perform (@RequestParam String strategyName) {
    Strategy strategy = (Strategy) /* Get the concrete Strategy based on strategyName */;
    strategy.doStuff ();
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can look it up programmatically:

```
private @Autowired BeanFactory beanFactory;

@RequestMapping("/blabla")
public void perform (@RequestParam String strategyName) {
    Strategy strategy = beanFactory.getBean(strategyName, Strategy.class);
    strategy.doStuff();
}
```

You could do it a fancier way using a custom `WebArgumentResolver`, but that's a lot more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: It would be safer to put the lookup behind a map, where the @RequestParam corresponds to a key in the map, and the Strategy implementation bean (or bean name) corresponds to a value in the map.  This way you won't leak your bean names to the presentation layer, and you will be able to change bean names without breaking your request contract.

Comment: @James Is there a solution with Spring autowired annotation?

Comment: @earldouglas: could u please let us know where and how to set the map as u mentioned?

Comment: darshan: You could change the above to `beanFactory.getBean(beansByStrategyName.get(strategyName), Strategy.class);`, making a map named `beansByStrategyName` accessible from `perform()`.